# Fill in a shape with color in java

Tags: java, swing, colors, shapes

I want to be able to make a program with three shapes: a circle, a square and a triangle. It needs to have buttons with name of the colors. If I click the red button for example and then click the circle, then the circle will turn into red.

My code is based on something I found that randomizes the color of the shapes with every click. I managed do a layout on the buttons but they won't appear with the shapes. Also the triangle isn't there. The actionlisteners to the buttons are commented out because I couldn't get them to work and I didn't want to erase them.

I'm very new to shapes and I can't get the thinking down. Thanks in advance!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DemoShapes {
       public static final Color DEFAULT_COLOR = Color.BLACK;

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Shapes");
Container contentPane;
JButton Red = new JButton("Red");
JButton Orange = new JButton("Orange");
JButton Yellow = new JButton ("Yellow");
JButton Green = new JButton ("Green");
JButton Blue = new JButton ("Blue");
JButton Pink = new JButton ("Pink");
JButton White = new JButton ("White");
JButton Gray = new JButton ("Gray");
JButton Black = new JButton ("Black");
JButton Back = new JButton ("Back to Menu");
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();

public DemoShapes() {


    ArrayList<ShapeItem> shapes = new ArrayList<ShapeItem>();

    shapes.add(new ShapeItem(new Ellipse2D.Double(1, 1, 100, 100),
            DEFAULT_COLOR));
    shapes.add(new ShapeItem(new Rectangle2D.Double(110, 1, 100, 100),
            DEFAULT_COLOR));
Polygon triangle = new Polygon();

contentPane = frame.getContentPane();


Red.setBounds (150, 380, 110, 30);
Orange.setBounds (290, 380, 110, 30);
Yellow.setBounds (430, 380, 110, 30);
Green.setBounds (150, 430, 110, 30);
Blue.setBounds (290, 430, 110, 30);
Pink.setBounds (430, 430, 110, 30);
White.setBounds (150, 480, 110, 30);
Gray.setBounds (290, 480, 110, 30);
Black.setBounds (430, 480, 110, 30);
Back.setBounds (5, 5, 170, 30);


panel1.add(Red);
//Red.addActionListener(this);
panel1.add(Orange);
//Orange.addActionListener(this);
panel1.add(Yellow);
//Yellow.addActionListener(this);
panel1.add(Green);
//Green.addActionListener(this);
panel1.add(Blue);
//Blue.addActionListener(this);
panel1.add(Pink);
//Pink.addActionListener(this);
panel1.add(White);
//White.addActionListener(this);
panel1.add(Gray);
//Gray.addActionListener(this);
panel1.add(Black);
//Black.addActionListener(this);
panel1.add(Back);
//Back.addActionListener(this);

    ShapesPanel panel = new ShapesPanel(shapes);
panel1.setLayout(null);
    frame.add(panel);
//frame.add(panel1);    
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(700,600);
frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

class ShapeItem {
    private Shape shape;
    private Color color;

    public ShapeItem(Shape shape, Color color) {
        super();
        this.shape = shape;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Shape getShape() {
        return shape;
    }

    public void setShape(Shape shape) {
        this.shape = shape;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}


class ShapesPanel extends JPanel {
    private List<ShapeItem> shapes;
    private Random rand = new Random();

    public ShapesPanel(List<ShapeItem> shapesList) {
        this.shapes = shapesList;

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

                Color color = getRandomColor();
                for (ShapeItem item : shapes) {
                    if (item.getShape().contains(e.getPoint())) {
                        item.setColor(color);
                    }
                }
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }


    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();

        for (ShapeItem item : shapes) {
            g2.setColor(item.getColor());
            g2.fill(item.getShape());
        }

        g2.dispose();
    }


    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(300, 300);
    }

    private Color getRandomColor() {
        return new Color(rand.nextFloat(), rand.nextFloat(),
            rand.nextFloat());
    }
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
                new DemoShapes();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you should try to tackle smaller parts of the project at once, and not copy other code and try to shoehorn your own logic into a workflow you don't understand. Are you able to start with a clean slate and have buttons which update some text to say which color / shape is being selected? Once you've got that, then you can look into starting with a single shape and seeing if you can change the its fill. I'm sure SO will be more willing to help with code of your own, rather than some you've copied.

Answer (score 3):

Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.

> I managed do a layout on the buttons but they won't appear with the shapes

You are using a null layout. Don't use a null layout and don't use setBounds(...). The layout manager will set the size/location of each component.

You have 10 buttons so I will suggest you might start with a `GridLayout`.

```
panel1.setLayout ( new GridLayout(0, 5) );
panel1.add(red);
...
```

The default layout manager for a JFrame is a `BorderLayout`:

```
frame.add(panel);
//frame.add(panel1);
```

When you don't specify a constraint then the component is added to the CENTER. Problem is only one component can be added to the CENTER so you need to specify different constraints:

```
frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.add(panel1, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples.